# Using native translations in custom pages

Tags: apex, visualforce, translation, locale

Salesforce corporation has done most of the work translating the out-of-the-box app into a few dozen languages.  This includes translations of Object, Field and Action names, which are relatively easy to access (using `$ObjectType` and `QuickAction.describe...`, respectively) but it also includes standard translations for Save and Cancel and the like.

As a developer making new Salesforce screens, in order to:

- make my user experience consistent,
- reuse work that Salesforce has already done, and
- use translator time wisely,

how do I make use of standard translations like *Save* and *Cancel*?

Comment: Looked at the translation workbench?

Comment: @Girbot yes.  Is there some way to access these pre-translated fields in there?  If so, please post an answer or comment explaining that.